# Progressive Matrix Question - circles inside squares

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image]

Can't seem to find the answer anywhere online. Anybody want to take a stab at it and explain their answer?

Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Raven_Progressive_Matrix.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's:

> C. The number of dots in each row is $n,n+1,n-2$. The columns start $5,6,7$, and C is the only box with $5$ dots.

Comment: To clarify this, because it confused me at first: rot13(Guvf ersref gb gur guerr ebjf bs obkrf (abg avar ebjf bs qbgf). Pynver'f zrgubq, ba gur bgure unaq, ersref gb gur avar pbyhzaf bs qbgf (abg guerr pbyhzaf bs obkrf).).

Comment: @EdMurphy; It counts the number of dots in the whole box, and then looks for a pattern in these. Claire's method is the same, but finds the vertical pattern which is admittedly a lot simpler than the one I found!

Answer (score 1):

You could also find the answer using vertical columns rather than rows. Each column is n, n+1, n+2. The lower right box needs to have 5 dots.